# Asus G550 screen goes black after resume from suspend, even though the system is responsive on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, screen, lid

My Ubuntu 16.04 system running on ASUS ROC laptop cannot resume from suspend. More specifically, after closing the lid, and then opening it back, during resume from suspend, the screen will go black and (sometimes) a white line will flash at the top of the screen. The lcd is on I believe, since I am able to reduce/increase brightness of the screen, it is simply pitch black. I have also noticed that the system is responsive, since I have been able to login and reboot by typing from memory. The problem sometimes immediately occurs after opening the lid of the laptop, and sometimes right after login. Another important thing I have noticed is that if I go through this suspend/resume cycle for about 3-4 times each time this problem occurs, the problem will go away unless I suspend the system again. An additional thing I have noticed is that in each case of black screen, firefox was open.

Following the advice of a kind person on IRC, I first tried the solution in [this link](http://iam.tj/prototype/enhancements/Windows-acpi_osi.html), which did not solve it. Then, I tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`, which also did not work. Afterwards, I tried switching PRIME profiles through `nvidia-settings` (Nvidia X Server Settings program), but that didn't work either. Lastly, I tried following the first set of instructions [on this page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend) and used`pm_trace`, but the only interesting line I got from `dmesg` was `acpi device:22: hash matches`, which I couldn't track back to anything. Any help is much appreciated!

Graphics hardware:

`VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller`
`3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 850M]`

Comment: If you have a separate monitor available, it would be useful to see what happens when you connect that. If the monitor stays on, it's a hardware problem with the laptop screen.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The thing is, after about 3 suspend cycles to get the screen back on, the screen doesn't go black again unless I suspend the system/reboot. Why would that be?